# My content gets shifted to the right side when in mobile mode

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, navigation-drawer

Making a Drawer in React.Js with Material-UI. 
When I switch to the mobile view, the Drawer content automatically shifts to the right side with a lot of margin.

It works fine the in desktop view.
I am not able to find the error in this code.

Could anyone guide me how can I solve this issue?

The code for the drawer:

```
import React from 'react';
[import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import Hidden from '@material-ui/core/Hidden';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';

import List from '@material-ui/core/List';

import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ListItem } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Data } from './data';



const drawerWidth = 240;


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({

  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },


  drawer: {
    \[theme.breakpoints.up('sm')\]: {
      width: drawerWidth,
      flexShrink: 0,
    },
  },
  appBar: {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    \[theme.breakpoints.up('sm')\]: {
      width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    },
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    \[theme.breakpoints.up('sm')\]: {
      display: 'none',
    },
  },
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));

function ResponsiveDrawer(props) {
  const { container } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const \[mobileOpen, setMobileOpen\] = React.useState(false);
  var \[index, changeindex\] = React.useState(1);

  function handleDrawerToggle() {
    setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);

  }

  const drawer = (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <Divider></Divider>

      <List>
              <ListItem button primary full large onClick = {()=>changeindex(index = 1)}  > <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
                  Test 1

              </Typography></ListItem>
              <ListItem button primary full large onClick={() => changeindex(index = 2)} >
                  <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
                      Test2
                  </Typography>


              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button primary full large onClick={() => changeindex(index = 3)}  >
                  <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
                      Test3
                  </Typography>


              </ListItem>


      </List>
    </div>
  );
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            edge="start"
            onClick={handleDrawerToggle}
            className={classes.menuButton}
          >
                      <i class="material-icons">view_headline</i>
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Responsive drawer

          </Typography>

        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <nav className={classes.drawer} aria-label="mailbox folders">
        {/* The implementation can be swapped with js to avoid SEO duplication of links. */}
        <Hidden smUp implementation="css">
          <Drawer
            container={container}
            variant="temporary"
            anchor={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'right' : 'left'}
            open={mobileOpen}
            onClose={handleDrawerToggle}

            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper,
            }}
            ModalProps={{
              keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
            }}
          >
            {drawer}
          </Drawer>
        </Hidden>
        <Hidden xsDown implementation="css">
          <Drawer
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper,
            }}
            variant="permanent"
            open
          >
            {drawer}
          </Drawer>
        </Hidden>
      </nav>
      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        {/* {console.log(index)} */}


                  <Data index={index}  ></Data>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}



ResponsiveDrawer.propTypes = {
  /**
   * Injected by the documentation to work in an iframe.
   * You won't need it on your project.
   */
  container: PropTypes.instanceOf(typeof Element === 'undefined' ? Object : Element),
};

export default ResponsiveDrawer;][1]
```

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVhmd.png)

Comment: Can you create a codepen?

Comment: It's navigation menu not hide in mobile view so contents get shift in right

Comment: Yes I understand that, can you provide a working example?

Comment: Can you create a Codesandbox or Codepen for others to see what's not right?